# Problems with DLL & threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

Please help me the following problems:

- I implement a thread doing some jobs. This thread implicitly calls some external DLLs. Of course, I tried my best to handle possible errors in those DLLs (using try ... catch) but cannot handle unexpected errors (e.g. memory exception).
- If one of DLLs encounters problem(s) (bug or loop somewhere) and eventually gets stuck, this thread will never be completed (or close).

In my program, each thread is associated with a session (number of sessions is limited). Assume all threads get stuck, incoming session will have to wait forever.

Is there any way to force a thread to stop even if it is still working or gets stuck?

Note that I am using C++ programming with Boost library.

Any advises are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operating system's libraries probably have a function to forcefully terminate a thread, but this is a bad idea unless you're absolutely certain of what those DLLs are doing. On Windows, this would be `TerminateThread`. For POSIX, I believe it's `pthread_cancel`.

The problem with terminating a thread externally is that any resources the thread was holding on to will be leaked. For example, any open files the thread had open will remain open, and any allocations it made will leak.

It's better to make sure your DLL never gets stuck. Instead of terminating the thread, I would log something and debug where and why the problem occurred.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The problem is that some of DLLs were implemented by others and the source codes are not available. I cannot know exactly what they are doing in those DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can [terminate a thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it sounds as if you need to have some kind of framework around your threads.

One way to do this is to have a watchdog thread that monitors all threads. By regularly checking to see if the threads are running as expected you can determine whether one (or more) threads need to be terminated.

To determine if a thread is working can be done by for instance by having a message queue in each thread and then use some custom messages to exchange status.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't have access to library source and have absolutely no way to control its behavior then probably the safiest solution would be to use separate processes instead of threads. Certainly this would require a much more elaborate solution on feeding workers with data and fetching their results, but at least you could safely kill hung workers and handle their tasks (send them to "not completed mailbox", restart etc).

Maybe, depending on the nature of the work being done, you should look at Boost.MPI.